# Is there any way to check two generic types with one type check in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below, the type of both `from` and `to` is the generic type `T`, but just checking that `to` is `string` doesn't make TypeScript understand that `from` is also `string`. I don't want to have to also check `from`, is there some way to just do this with a single check?

```js
function mergeData<T>(from: T, to: T) : T {
    if(typeof to === 'string')
        return to + from // Error : Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(to).slice(8, -1) === 'Array')
        return to.concat(from) // Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'T'.
    // ...
}
```

I tried doing this:

```js
interface Parent {
    name: string
}
interface ChildNumber extends Parent{
    name: string
    number: number
}
interface ChildObject extends Parent {
    name: string
    object: { a: number }
}
function isChildNumber(obj: any) : obj is ChildNumber {
    return 'number' in obj
}
function isChildObject(obj: any) : obj is ChildObject {
    return 'object' in obj
}
function mergeData<T extends Parent>(from: T, to: T) : T {
    if(isChildNumber(from))
        return to.number + from.number // Error : Property 'number' does not exist on type 'T'.
    if(isChildObject(from))
        return to.object.a + from.object.a // Property 'object' does not exist on type 'T'.
}
```

This code doesn't give any changes. ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly a perfectly valid invocation of your function signature:

```
mergeData<string | number>('asd', 123)
```

If your function is called in such a way, then `typeof to === 'string'` would return `true`, but `from` would be of type `number`.

`to` and `from` are both guaranteed to be subtypes of `T`, but they may be different subtypes of `T`. And that means that you will need to test both variables at runtime in order to be sure.

Comment: Fantastic point, it's so easy to forget union types! Example demonstrating the above with `ChildObject` and `ChildNumber` in the playground: https://tsplay.dev/NrvKzN *"`to` and `from` are both guaranteed to be subtypes of `T`, but they may be different subtypes of `T`."* Couldn't be clearer.